# ReEdited : Audio not playing in real ios Device but playing in simulated devices in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, swift2

This is my code in swift2 , absolutely no error ,Im running on a real device but no sound is coming ? no exceptions nothing am I missing something?

```
  import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func play() {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


         let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("drum", ofType: "mp3")!)

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            audioPlayer.play()
            print("yes")

        }catch _ {
            audioPlayer = nil
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Im suspecting is it because my simulated device is ios9 and my real device is ios 8.4

Comment: what happens if you use an iOS 8.4 Simulator?

Comment: how do you change the version of simulator?

Comment: Preferences->Downloads->Components->iOS 8.4 Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem from one of the videos of Apple's WWDC Conference

http://adcdownload.apple.com/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_412__audio_development_for_iphone_os_part_1.mov (only viewable on safari)

The problem was audio routing , when i plugged in the earphone I could listen to the sound from  the real device . 
When the route is changed we need to set the proper audio routing using AVAudioSession . More info in that video above.

Answer (score 0):

Import AVFoundation and add this to your viewDidLoad:

var err = NSErrorPointer()
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: err)